# Why 'exclude' option is not working in tsconfig?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, tsconfig

I am writing an admin panel on the nuxt + nest stack.

I'm using this template: https://github.com/stephsalou/nuxt-nest-template

When I work locally, there are no errors related to the server, but when I run mode build, ts wants to prototype the files that are in node_modules

Package.json

```json
  "scripts": {
    "nuxt": "nuxt",
    "nest": "nest start",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_TYPE=docker IS_NUXT_ENABLED=true nodemon",
    "dev:production": "cross-env NODE_TYPE=production IS_NUXT_ENABLED=true nodemon",
    "dev:client": "nuxt",
    "dev:server": "nodemon",
    "build": "NODE_TYPE=production run-s clean:dist compile:server compile:client client:generate copy:.nuxt copy:client copy:config",
    "clean:dist": "rimraf dist",
    "compile:server/*this script throws an error*/": "tsc --listFiles -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "compile:client": "cross-env mode=production nuxt build",
    "client:generate": "cross-env mode=production nuxt generate",
    "copy:client": "copyfiles -a \\\"client/**/*\\\" dist",
    "copy:.nuxt": "copyfiles -a \".nuxt/**/*\" dist",
    "copy:config": "copyfiles nuxt.config.ts package.json package-lock.json dist",
    "analytics:dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch --config ./static/js/analytics/webpack",
    "analytics:build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./static/js/analytics/webpack"
  },
```

tsconfig

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/server",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    // "incremental": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "ESNext.AsyncIterable", "DOM"],
    // "esModuleInterop": true,
    // "allowJs": true,
    // "strict": true,
    // "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./server/*"],
      "@/*": ["./client/*"]
    },
     "types": ["@types/node", "@nuxt/types", "@types/sequelize"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**/*", ".nuxt", "dist"]
}
```

tsconfig.build

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "server/**/*"
  ]
}
```

[image]
[image]

Why might it not work??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this i related to tsconfig at all.
The libs should be included in compilation as they are part of the applications. Adding the property

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

are many times the fix for theese kinds of errors as it skips checking `*.d.ts`(lib files). But not in your case as it is there.

First I would check node versions, yarn version etc.

I successfully tried the template using `yarn build`

```
node v14.7.0
yarn v1.22.15
```

Then the `include` and `exclude` look a bit strange I think.
If I remember correct `include` and `exclude` is overwritten when extending. So you might need to specify them explicitly in both config files.

I.e

In tsconfig.json

```
"exclude": ["node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist"]
```

In tsconfig.build.json (make sure to exclude the tests)

```
"exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"],
"include": ["server"]
```